# Making the Plus and Minus quantity button go up in increments of 8 in woocommerce 2.0.10

Tags: increment, woocommerce

I've read a lot a questions and answers, specially in this one "Making the +/- Plus and Minus quantity button go up in increments of 12 in woocommerce", but in woocommerce 2.0.10 it seems to be coded differently because I can't figure out where to change the 1 by the 12 suggested by Ewout.
I don't know js but I can follow specific instructions.
I'm using VarkTech Minimum Purchase for WooCommerce plugin and with 2 rules I've solved two of the three requirement. One was the minimun purchase per item of 16, the other was a minimum order of 48 in the total of products purchased, but the last requirement is that I need that the increments of the minus/plus buttons to be 8.
I'll appreciate very much if anybody can explain a little bit more the answer that Ewout gave to Artmart.
Sorry for my english.
Regards from Chile,
Monica

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my previous comment, in WooCommerce 2.1 you can directly filter the step value. Put this in a [site-specific plugin](http://ottopress.com/2011/creating-a-site-specific-snippets-plugin/).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'kia_quantity_input_step', 10, 2 );
function kia_quantity_input_step( $step, $product ){
    return 6; // the will be the new step value
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'kia_quantity_input_min', 10, 2 );
function kia_quantity_input_step( $min, $product ){
    return 16; // the will be the new min value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place following code in any php file of any plugin and make sure that the plugin is in active mode, it should work exactly as you want. Read the comments in code & modify values as per your requirement

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_filter_to_overwrite_increment' );

function add_filter_to_overwrite_increment() {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'overwrite_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
}

function overwrite_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    $args['input_value'] = 8; // Starting quantity value
    $args['max_value'] = 100; // Quantity can not go beyond this value
    $args['min_value'] = 1;   // Quantity cannot go below this value
    $args['step'] = 8;        // Value with which you want to increment or decrement
    return $args;
}
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Hi Ratnakar.Thanks for your help. I pasted it in my child theme's functions.php and it works. The problem that I still have is that it starts with 1 product and it increnments in 8, so 1+8=9. I need it to be: 16+8+8+8+8... It's the first "1" that should be 16. I've tried changing the 'min_value' to 16, but I still get a 1. Any clue how to solve it?

Comment: Try setting `$args['input_value'] = 16;` and `$args['min_value'] = 16;` in above code

Comment: I did it and I still have the same problem. It still starts with 1 as minimum purchase and goes up in increments of 8, getting 9, 17, 25... as results. Besides, I realised that the increments works only in single products page, not in the cart page. Another suggestion? Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the bleeding edge of WooCommerce 2.1 you can filter `woocommerce_quantity_input_min` directly and set that to 8. Then filter `woocommerce_quantity_input_step` to be 8. That should get you 8,16,24, etc. I have no idea if these filters are in WC2.0.?